# How to connect two exisitng Objects in Rails via onclick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have User Model and Car Model. 
 
I show a add button in the cars/index.html.erb for every Car so that a User can add any Car he want.
And in the users/show.html.erb i want to list all the Cars he added.
 
The Problem is, it connect not only the clicked Car to the User, but also all other cars in the cars/index.html.erb.

user.erb and car.erb

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :cars 
end

class Car << ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

cars/index.html.erb

```
 <% @car.each do |car| %>
    #...
    <td><%= link_to 'Get Car', '#', :onclick => get_car(car.id) %></td>
    #...
 <% end %>
```

cars_helper.rb

```
def get_car(id)
 current_user.cars << Car.find_by(id: id)
end
```

user/show.html.erb

```
<% if @user.cars.any? %>  
<% @user.cars.each do |c| %>
   <%= c.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is `@user` could it be falling out of scope some how? I don't actually see how this logic is processing because you are using javascript but I don't see any javascript code here?

Comment: You can not call a helper method from javascript. I can suggest you some code for do it without javascript but will need to refresh the page. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes ok, for the moment its all i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

cars/index.html.erb

```
<% @car.each do |car| %>
#...
  <%= link_to 'Get Car', get_car_path(:id => car.id)   %>
#...
<% end %>
```

cars_controllers.rb

```
def get_car
  @user = current_user
  @user.cars = Car.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to cars_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end 
end
```

routes.rb

```
match '/cars/get_car' => 'cars#get_car', :as => :get_car
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand your code, but i get the error "Couldn't find Car with 'id'=get_car" in the set_car method.

Comment: in route.rb place the code on the top, before resources

Comment: I dont test the code, maybe doesnt work for x reason but it is an idea

Comment: Your right, put before the resources and it works fine.